# Why can I get null when I get a bean from spring?

Tags: spring, spring-bean

My 'applicationContext.xml' file for spring is:

```
<bean id="gzipResponseInterceptor" class="my.interceptor.GzipResponseInterceptor"/>

<bean id="addResponseInterceptor" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref local="httpClient"/>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>addResponseInterceptor</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="gzipResponseInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager" p:defaultMaxPerRoute="100"
              p:maxTotal="100"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then in my Java code:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
System.out.println(context.getBean("gzipResponseInterceptor"));
System.out.println(context.getBean("addResponseInterceptor"));
System.out.println(context.getBean("httpClient"));
```

And it prints:

```
my.interceptor.GzipResponseInterceptor@525f1e4e
null
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient@75f9eccc
```

Notice the value of the bean 'addResponseInterceptor' is `null`! I can't understand why I can get `null` for a spring bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addResponseInterceptor` is a `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` which sole purpose is, as the name implies, to invoke a method. When doing `context.getBean("addResponseInterceptor")` what is being returned is the result of the `getObject` method of the `FactoryBean`.

The [`MethodInvokingFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) returns the result of the invoked method.

Judging by the name of the method being invoked, `addResponseInterceptor`, that is `void`. `void` or `Void` results in a `null` result to be return from the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`.

If you want the actual `FactoryBean` add a `&` to the name of the bean you want to retrieve. See last part of [section 5.8.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) of the reference guide.